# FreeRadius "failed to execute ntlm_auth: permission denied"

Tags: freeradius

I installed FreeRadius on Ubunto and I'm trying to understand how configure it to authenticate against Active Directory.
I'm kinda new to linux so I followed the user guides and some forums thread to configure Samba, MSCHAP and ntlm_auth.
When I try to test it using the command:
"radtest -t mschap testing password localhost 0 testing123"

I get the error:

```
(0) mschap: ERROR: Program returned code (2) and output 'Failed to execute "/etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-enabled/ntlm_auth": Permission denied'
(0) mschap: External script failed
(0) mschap: ERROR: External script says: Failed to execute "/etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-enabled/ntlm_auth": Permission denied
(0) mschap: ERROR: MS-CHAP2-Response is incorrect
```

I don't understand what am I missing in the configuration.
would appreciate some help

I tried setting explicit permissions manually on ntlm_auth but that didn't help. I got another error:

```
(0) mschap: ERROR: Program returned code (2) and output 'Failed to execute "/etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-enabled/ntlm_auth": Exec format error'
(0) mschap: External script failed
(0) mschap: ERROR: External script says: Failed to execute "/etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-enabled/ntlm_auth": Exec format error
(0) mschap: ERROR: MS-CHAP2-Response is incorrect
```

Thanks